# System.out redirection to JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, stream, nullpointerexception

```
package htmlconsole;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class HTMLConsole extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextPane textPane;

    public class Interceptor extends PrintStream
    {
        public Interceptor(OutputStream out)
        {
            super(out,true);
        }
        @Override
        public void print(String s)
        {
            super.print(s);
            textPane.setText(textPane.getText()+s);
        }

        @Override 
        public void println(String s)
        {
            super.println(s);
            textPane.setText(textPane.getText()+"\n<br>");
        }       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    HTMLConsole frame = new HTMLConsole();
                    frame.setVisible(true);

                    System.out.println("Hello");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public HTMLConsole() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setEditable(false);
        textPane.setContentType("text/html");
        textPane.setText("");

        contentPane.add(textPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //redirect stream
        PrintStream interceptor = new Interceptor(System.out);
        System.setOut(interceptor);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Hellojava.lang.NullPointerException
    at console.Console$Interceptor.print(Console.java:29)
    at java.io.PrintStream.println(Unknown Source)
    at console.Console$Interceptor.println(Console.java:35)
    at console.Console$1.run(Console.java:47)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How should I correct this program? It's very confusing that the exception is being thrown inside "print" method which hadn't been used!

**UPDATE:**

Exception disappeared after replacing `JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();` by `textPane = new JTextPane();`, but now nothing is being shown inside the window.[image]

Comment: It's definitely called, since you're calling `System.setOut(interceptor);`, and then calling `System.out.println("Hello");`, which itself calls `print()`.

Comment: See also [`JTextComponent.read(Reader,Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29).  Also `setContentType("text/html");` does not make sense, since the output of the console is *not* HTML in any sense of the word.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Ok, I've renamed my class to "HTMLConsole".

Comment: @0x6B6F77616C74: you didn't understand what Andrew meant. You're telling the JTextPane that it will have to display HTML, and what you set as text in the JTextPane is what you send to System.out.println(), which is plain text, and not HTML. Regarding your second problem, part of it is the last point in my answer, and part of it is the fact that you don't append to the text pane, but replace its content each time something is printed to System.out, and part of it is that you're using text/html when it should be plain text/plain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your constructor calls

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane(); // local variable declaration and initialization
```

instead of calling

```
this.textPane = new JTextPane()
```

So the `textPane` field, used by the interceptor, is null.

Also note that, as the stack trace shows, `super.println()` calls `print()`. That will cause every String passed to println() to be appended to the text pane twice.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement your requirements using swing's MVC capabilities. Since a JTextPane has a document model you should think about adapting the model to the stream.

```
public class DocumentPrintStream extends PrintStream {

    public DocumentPrintStream(Document document, OutputStream delegateStream) {
        super(delegateStream);
        this.document = document;
    }

    @Override
    public void print(String string) {
        int offset = document.getLength();
        try {
            document.insertString(offset, string, null);
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        }
        super.print(string); // write to the delegate stream
    }
}

public Console() {
    ...
    JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
    contentPane.add(textPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // redirect stream
    Document document = textPane.getDocument();
    DocumentPrintStream documentPrintStream = new DocumentPrintStream(
            document, System.out);
    System.setOut(documentPrintStream );
}
```

It has also the befefit that you can reuse the `DocumentPrintStream` with every component that is based on a `Document` model.

For example:

- JEditorPane
- JTextArea
- JTextField
- JTextPane

Answer (score 2):

You're shadowing the variable `textPane` in the constructor of `Console`. Replace

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
```

with

```
textPane = new JTextPane();
```